Solve recurrence relation
I am trying to figure out how to solve recurrence relations of type
$$f(n) = af(n-1) + (bn + c)f(n-2)$$
I will be grateful for any tips or books.

Mathematica's command RSolve cannot do anything with this recurrence, even with $c=0$. So, an explicit solution is unlikely to exist here.

By substituting $f(n)=a^n g(n)$ you can assume $a=1$.  Then the generating function of the solution satisfies a differential equation of order 3 but I don't know if there is an explicit solution.

an exponential generating function?

This is a problem statement question. Maybe it needs more details

Linear ODEs with coefficients linear in the variable, and linear recurrence relations with linear coefficients can be solved by the so called Laplace's method.

May I ask where it shows up ?

@Olivier In my case it shows up in my experiments with integer partitions.

The publication Closed-form solutions of general second order linear recurrences and applications may be helpful. It gives two forms of solution for
$$f(n)=b_{n-1}f(n-1)+a_{n-2}f(n-2).$$
One solution is given in terms of the recursively defined coefficients $d_1=b_0$, $d_n=b_{n-1}+a_{n-2}/d_{n-1}$
by
\begin{gather*}
f(n)=f(0)\mathcal D'_n+f(1)\mathcal E'_n,\;\;n\geq 2 \\
\mathcal D'_n \mathrel{:=} a_0\sum_{i = 2}^n \left(\prod_{j = 2}^{i - 1} \frac{a_{j - 1}}{-d_j}\cdot\prod_{k = i}^{n - 1} d_{k + 1}\right),\;\mathcal E'_n \mathrel{:=} \sum_{i = 1}^n \left(\prod_{j = 1}^{i - 1} \frac{a_{j - 1}}{-d_j}\cdot\prod_{k = i}^{n - 1} d_{k + 1}\right).
\end{gather*}

An explicit answer is obtained for the special case $$f(n)=\alpha f(n-1)-(n-1)f(n-2),$$ initial conditions $f(0)=1$, $f(1)=\alpha$,
$$f(n)=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}\frac{\alpha^{n-2k}(-1)^kn!}{(n-2k)!k!2^k}.$$
For $\alpha=-1$ this is the (probabilist's) Hermite polynomial $-H_n(-1)$, see https://oeis.org/A001464.

For some reason, part of your formula for $f(n)$ was in TeX code, and part was an image.  I assumed that it was preferable to have the whole in TeX code, and transcribed it.  I hope that was all right.

This type of equations can be solved in terms of "factorial series", as explained in the book:
N. E. Nørlund, Leçons sur les équations linéaires aux differences finies, Paris, Gauthier-Villars, 1929. Chap II.
This method gives a solution analytic in your independent variable $n$ in a right half-plane.
An alternative method of @Brendan McKay leads to
a 3-d order Fuchsian ODE for the generating function which can be solved in the form of a series by Frobenius method, but this leads to another difference equation.
Remark. For those who does not read French, there is a nice English source:
Paul M Batchelder, An Introduction to Linear Difference Equations,  Harvard University Press
1927. Chap. IV, section 4. (Available on Internet.)
This book addresses exactly the special type of
difference equations in the question. See, for example formula (246) on p. 203 which is almost
exactly your equation, and the next two formulas
describe its solution.
The solution is obtained in the form of a definite integral or a series.

Here is  a derivation of the generating function as a solution of an ODE of the first order with Maple 2024 (see here for info).
with(gfun):deq := rectodiffeq({f(n) = a*f(n - 1) + (b*n + c)*f(n - 2)}, f(n), g(t));

$$\left(-2 t^{2} b -t^{2} c -a t +1\right) g \! \left(t \right)-b \,t^{3} \left(\frac{d}{d t}g \! \left(t \right)\right)+a t \textit{_C}_{0}-\textit{_C}_{1} t -\textit{_C}_{0}
 $$
dsolve(deq);

$$g \! \left(t \right) = 
\left({\int}\frac{\left(a t \textit{_C}_{0}-\textit{_C}_{1} t -\textit{_C}_{0}\right) t^{-\frac{-c +b}{b}} {\mathrm e}^{-\frac{2 a t -1}{2 t^{2} b}}}{b}{d}t +c_{1} \right) t^{-\frac{c}{b}-2} {\mathrm e}^{\frac{2 a t -1}{2 t^{2} b}}
 $$
